# Burninate the CSharp tag!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Tag [csharp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csharp) has 0 questions asked here.

**Let's *burninate it* before its existence becomes widely known...**

<sub>...or make it a synonym of [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23)</sub>.

Comment: +1 for the proper terminology (and valid tag). :-)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! I would love to see Csharp burn! Let's all use Java instead :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tag only existed as a synonym for [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) which is obviously incorrect. Removing the synonym caused the tag to disappear, so this can be considered resolved.